# how to make Nokogiri not to convert &nbsp; to space

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, html-entities

i fetch one html fragment like

```
"<li>市&nbsp;场&nbsp;价"
```

which contains "`&nbsp;`", but after calling `to_s` of Nokogiri NodeSet, it becomes

```
"<li>市 场 价"
```

, i want to keep the original html fragment, and tried to set `:save_with option` for `to_s` method, but failed.

can someone encounter the same problem and give me help? thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to ask this at [nokogiri-talk](http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I encountered a similar situation, and what I came up was a bit of a hack, but it seems to work well.

```
nbsp = Nokogiri::HTML("&nbsp;").text
text.gsub(nbsp, " ")
```

In my case, I wanted the nbsp to be a regular space.  I think in your case, you want them to be returned to a "&nbsp;", so you could do something like:

```
nbsp = Nokogiri::HTML("&nbsp;").text
html.gsub(nbsp, "&nbsp;")
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, and I've been busting my head against this for a few hours. Thank you!

Comment: def strip_html(str)
  nbsp = Nokogiri::HTML("&nbsp;").text
  str.gsub(nbsp,'')
end

Comment: this is not a generic solution, what if you want it to preserve all html entities?  Like &mdash; &quot; etc etc

Comment: If it bothers you to run the superfluous `nbsp = Nokogiri::HTML("&nbsp;").text`,  you can get the pattern for your gsub with `nbsp = 160.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)`. 160 is the extended ASCII code for a nonbreaking space; it's what Nokogiri  returns when it parses '&nbsp'.

Answer (score 11):

I think the problem is how you're looking at the string. It will look like a space, but it's not quite the same:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('"<li>市&nbsp;场&nbsp;价"')
(doc % 'li').content.chars.to_a[1].ord # => 160
(doc % 'li').to_html # => "<li>市 场 价\"</li>"
```

A regular space is `32`, `0x20` or `' '`. `160` is the decimal value for a non-breaking-space, which is what `&nbsp;` converts to after you use Nokogiri's various `inner_text`, `content`, `text` or `to_s` tags. It's no longer a HTML entity-encoding, but it's still a non-breaking space. I think Nokogiri's conversion from the entity-encoding is the appropriate behavior when asking for a stringification.

There might be a flag to tell Nokogiri to NOT decode the value, but I'm not aware of it off-hand. You can check on Nokogiri's mail-list that I mentioned in the comment above, to see if there is a flag. I can see an advantage for Nokogiri to *not* do the decode also so if there isn't such a flag it would be nice occasionally.

Now, all that said, I think the `to_html` method SHOULD return the value to its entity-encoded value, since a non-breaking space is a nasty thing to encounter in a HTML stream. And *that* I think you should mention on the mail-list or maybe even as a bug. I think it's an inappropriate result.

---

http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk/msg/0b81ef0dc180dc74

> Okay, I can explain the behavior now.  Basically, the problem boils 
>   down to encoding.
>
> In Ruby 1.9, we examine the encoding of the string you're feeding to 
>   Nokogiri.  If the input string is "utf-8", the document is assumed to 
>   be a UTF-8 document.  When you output the document, since " " can 
>   be represented as a UTF-8 character, it is output as that UTF-8 
>   character.
>
> In 1.8, since we cannot detect the encoding of the document, we assume 
>   binary encoding and allow libxml2 to detect the encoding. 
>   If you set the encoding of the input document to binary, it will give 
>   you back the entities you want.  Here is some code to demo:

```
 require 'nokogiri' 
 html = '<body>hello &nbsp; world</body>' 
 f    = Nokogiri.HTML(html) 
 node = f.css('body') 
 p node.inner_html 
 f    = Nokogiri.HTML(html.encode('ASCII-8BIT')) 
 node = f.css('body') 
 p node.inner_html
```

> I posted a youtube video too!  :-)
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2SzhXAt7V4
>
> Aaron Patterson

Your sample text isn't `ASCII-8BIT` so try changing that encoding string to the Unicode character set name and see if `inner_html` will return an entity-encoded value.

Comment: Thank you i will try it according to what you point "to_html"

Comment: i just debuged and found that: nbsp; is converted by the code below  Nokogiri::HTML(fragment, nil, @encoding, NOKOGIRI_OPTIONS).search(rule_body), so i need to dig into and find why or you can give my help

Comment: I recommend asking at nokogiri-talk. The developers monitor that list and can give you the definitive answer.

Comment: ok, firstly i try to change the Nokogiri parse options and see the results, if that's no help, i will asking at nokogiri-talk, :-) i thank you very very much.

Comment: failed again, i need to ask nokogiri-talk, but in China i can not access http://groups.google.com/group/nokogiri-talk google groups, that is blocked by gov, could you tell me if there is other ways which i can use to ask? thank u.

Comment: The options control how liberal or strict the engine is when parsing the document. See [`Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/HTML/Document.html#method-c-parse) and [`Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/ParseOptions.html).

Comment: OK, I think I already have an answer, found in a response to a similar question by Aaron Patterson. See my edited answer.

Comment: Great, really there is STRICT parse mode, i will add it to parse option to see, but no effect, and i can not find literal parse mode.

Comment: By default HTML parsing is liberal and XML parsing is strict, mostly because HTML can be such a mess that using strict parsing will fail. The parsing mode won't affect the character set or whether entities are decoded though.

Comment: i use Nokogiri::HTML(fragment, nil, @encoding, NOKOGIRI_OPTIONS).search(rule_body), the NOKOGIRI_OPTIONS=Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::NOERROR | Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::NOWARNING, fragment is html string, is there any place i changed to xml parse mode? become confused.

Comment: You do NOT want XML parsing because you are parsing HTML. Read the links in the sixth comment to my answer for more info.

Comment: yes, i just read Aaron Patterson's answer and understand it's really caused by encoding. But now i don't want nbsp to go back entity space, if i don't set the encoding of html, nokogori can not parse it properly, so i must set the encoding for html string before passing to Nokoigir, once i set encoding just as Patterson said nbsp will go back to entity, but what i want is original nbsp even though i set the encoding for html string.

Comment: "what i want is original nbsp even though i set the encoding for html string." Then I'd suggest using [Nokogiri issues](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues) to raise the question as I don't think it's possible but the developers are the final authority.

Comment: ok, really really thank you very much for many times reply on my problem, i will try.